# Чтение числе из файла. PASCAL

Tags: pascal

Помогите написать подпрограмму , которая будет читать числа из файла и писать их в список.
Например, в файле написано: "10  100  59  3  2 45"
Я не могу придумать метод, как посчитать число, которое больше одного символа, как одно число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var 
  a, b, c, d, e, f: integer;
  file: TextFile;
begin
  ...
  ReadLn(file, a, b, c, d, e, f);
```

Comment: А что такое "a, b, c, d, e, f"? Это тип несколько элементов?